# setting gsettings of other user with sudo

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, sudo

On Ubuntu 13.10, I have all of my gsettings in a file, mygset.sh. For example, mygset.sh contains many lines such as

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "['application://nautilus.desktop', 'application://firefox.desktop', 'application://chromium-browser.desktop', 'unity://running-apps', 'unity://expo-icon', 'unity://devices']"
```

I have a master install script that I have to run with sudo (e.g. it does sudo apt-get install).
From that master install script I want to call `mygset.sh`. However, no matter how I call it it is not changing the settings for my user. I think it is changing the settings of root. I've tried it like (from `masterinstall.sh` which is being run as `sudo ./masterinstall.sh`):

```
sudo -u "wang" ./mygset.sh
sudo -u "wang" bash -c ./mygset.sh
```

Neither of those works (they run without error and change the setting [I check within the script with gsetting get] but not for user "wang").

When I run `mygset.sh` from the command line (without sudo: `bash ./mygset.sh`). It works perfectly. Why is there this difference and what can I do to solve it within `masterinstall.sh`?

Comment: You might want to try asking this on askubuntu.com

Comment: Hello Xu, I was just wondering if you might have had a chance to try the method I outlined below. Thanks!

Comment: @ssnobody thanks ssnobody, that's a good idea. But unfortunately the way my files are set up I need to run `mygset.sh` from within a script I'm running `sudo` on. I could refactor it but that would take some time and lead to less readable code. In any case, yours is the closest to an answer and indeed is an answer to this use case after some refactoring.

Comment: There is a similar question under http://askubuntu.com/questions/276509/change-gsettings-without-running-x-and-unity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you write a 'parent' script, which can then launch the masterinstall using sudo before running myget again as the local user. Examples follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo ./masterinstall.sh
./mygset.sh
```

Answer (score 10):

After trying a lot of stuff in different combinations this is the only command that worked for me:

```sh
sudo -H -u <user> DISPLAY=:0 DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/<uid>/bus gsettings set...
```

In a bash script you can use the following function to automatically detect the user and environment of a current session:

```sh
function run-in-user-session() {
    _display_id=":$(find /tmp/.X11-unix/* | sed 's#/tmp/.X11-unix/X##' | head -n 1)"
    _username=$(who | grep "\(${_display_id}\)" | awk '{print $1}')
    _user_id=$(id -u "$_username")
    _environment=("DISPLAY=$_display_id" "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$_user_id/bus")
    sudo -Hu "$_username" env "${_environment[@]}" "$@"
}
```

Use it like this:

```sh
run-in-user-session gsettings set...
```

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04. Changed it slightly to allow me to pass the user I wanted to run as.

Answer (score 6):

By default sudo sets the uid and the gid to the user you've specified but it doesn't change the environment settings etc.

Suggest you try `-H` first, which sets the `$HOME` variable to the target user:

```
sudo -u "wang" -H ./myget.sh
```

If that doesn't work, try `-i` which is supposed to simulate the initial login.

A slightly different tack, which I've found sometimes works, is to use `su`:

```
sudo su - wang
/full/path/to/myget.sh
exit
```

You'll need to use the full path to the script because the su command changes the current working directory.

Comment: +1 good ideas but they didn't work for me. Does any of them work for you?

Comment: I'm not running Unity, but I am running Gnome (on Mint).  So I can't set the specific `com.canonical.Unity.Launcher` setting. However the `su` method allows me to set other settings for the other user (specifically `org.gnome.nautilus.desktop background-fade`).   Maybe worth trying just the `gsettings` command after `sudo su - wang` ? (may not solve the whole problem, but might learn enough to progress to the next step).

Comment: I'm running Gnome version 3.6.0 according to gnome-terminal, which may make a difference.

Comment: The `sudo su - wang` strangely does not work. What happens is that it logs me in (I have byobu enabled), I then manually change directory and then run the mygset.sh script. And it doesn't work (even though it says wang@mycomp:~....). Well, it does not give an error so I don't know what it does but it doesn't change the appearance. I then exit and then run it manually and it immediately works.

Answer (score 3):

I have a POST-Install script that sets my gsetting. Because I run the script as sudo the EUID is 0, there fore I have to find the $RUID (Real User ID).

here is my approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Get the Real Username
RUID=$(who | awk 'FNR == 1 {print $1}')

# Translate Real Username to Real User ID
RUSER_UID=$(id -u ${RUID})

# Set gsettings for the Real User
sudo -u ${RUID} DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/${RUSER_UID}/bus" gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-date false

exit
```

Comment: I will study this solution. Thank you for the different approach.

Answer (score 2):

The gsettings command needs to know the bus address of the user's dbus session since dconf uses D-Bus, and thus `$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` need to be passed from the user's environment to root's environment while running the main script with sudo, and then from root's environment back to the user's environment while running the gsettings commands in the script with sudo. The whole environment can be preserved if the security wouldn't be a concern.

So, in this particular case, from the command line:

`sudo --preserve-env=DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS ./masterinstall.sh`
or
`sudo -E ./masterinstall.sh`

And, from inside masterinstall.sh:

`sudo -E -u wang ./mygset.sh`

If the GNOME settings were to be changed directly inside masterinstall.sh:

```
sudo -E -u wang bash <<- EOF
    gsettings set ...
    gsettings set ...
    EOF
```

Also, in the case where the gsettings commands had to be put in a separate script, and a third script is used only as a wrapper for the two scripts (as in the accepted answer), running the main script with sudo inside the wrapper script may be alright, but in the general case where several commands are run as root in a script that isn't run as root could require entering the root password multiple times depending on the time it takes to run the intermediate commands, and thus running the main script as root and changing to other users in the script as necessary with `sudo -u` is a better approach in general.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should run every `gsettings set ...` as the user whose settings should change:

```
sudo -u wang dbus-launch --exit-with-session gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "['application://nautilus.desktop', 'application://firefox.desktop', 'application://chromium-browser.desktop', 'unity://running-apps', 'unity://expo-icon', 'unity://devices']" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

There may be an error complaining about not creating *.dbus/session-bus*. Appending `>/dev/null 2>&1` will suppress them.

Please be aware that changeing settings on unmountes encrypted homes won't work.

When using ***pam_mount*** to automatically map remote shares the script will stop and wait for the pam_mount password.
You can workaround this by temporary deactivate pam_mount:

```
# deactivate pam_mount   
sed 's/@include common-session-noninteractive/#@include common-session-noninteractive/g' -i /etc/pam.d/sudo 
sed 's/session\toptional\tpam_mount.so/#session\toptional\tpam_mount.so/g' -i /etc/pam.d/common-session

# do your settings

# reactivate pam_mount   
sed 's/#@include common-session-noninteractive/@include common-session-noninteractive/g' -i /etc/pam.d/sudo 
sed 's/#session\toptional\tpam_mount.so/session\toptional\tpam_mount.so/g' -i /etc/pam.d/common-session
```